# Adding new key/value pair to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Now I want to add some new key/value pair at the end with:

```
addData ( $json );

function addData($json) {
    $obj = json_decode ( $json, true );

    $arr = array (
            "newKey" => "newValue" 
    );

    array_push ( $obj, $arr );
    $json = json_encode ( $obj );

    echo $json;
}
```

Unfortunately, I doesn't work. When outputting `$json` at the end of this function, it just returns the old json.

Comment: I think it's because your JSON is `object` and not `array`.

Comment: http://codepad.org/sWPAEtI9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your code shows that your code does work. The output becomes:

```
{"employees":[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}],"0":{"newKey":"newValue"}}
```

(notice the end of the line)

However, I don't think you are pushing the new key/value to the correct location.

Do the following if you want to push into the employees array:

```
array_push ( $obj['employees'], $arr );
```

If you just want to add to the top-most level, just do:

```
$obj['newKey'] = 'newValue';
$json = json_encode ( $obj );
```